# Phonegap Cross-Platflorm App getting Exernal Data

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, cordova, phonegap-cli

This is my first hybrid app and i am using CLI phonegap to develop it on a windows computer. i would like the app to be compatible with the latest versions of ios and android and i wouldn't mind if it was compatible with old versions of android as i know some phones can't upgrade to the latest version.

i need to develop a cross-platform app. The app will have multiple pages where different pages load different data from an external server. The app has a navigation drawer as well so that these different pages can be accessed. I'm not sure what the best way is to do this.

I can display data on the index page by making a call to a file on the external server which converts the data to json. i can do this for one page only and am not sure how to do it when i select a different page from the navigation drawer. because when i select a different page nothing loads. I would prefer to have the pages saved in dfferent files as there will be alot of pages and it will be too much if added all in the index page.

Please could you help as i have spent days trying to figure out the best way to set up my app.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**.
Since this appears to be your first post on this subject.
Is this your first hybrid App?
What is your target platform and their target versions? Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9?
What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS?
Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link.
Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Sorry, in review of your question, it is too broad. Stackoverflow is meant for technical answers to technical questions. You are asking an architectural. I'm going to give you an answer, but I will also suggest you ask on the [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AN11,
it appears you have knowledge on how to do what you want to accomplish. However, your biggest issue is "how to load *external data*".

**For the external sever**, the most typical way to load data from a REST API. Most can return (or are capable of returning) a JSON data structure. Many commercial services, such as firebase, strongloop, and parse.com (recently Facebook made open source), run as a [MBaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_backend_as_a_service) (*Mobile Backend As A Service*) and are free (with bandwidth constrained). You can also find a lot of open source solutions for PHP, Rudy, PERL and (of course) node.js.

**On the Cordova/Phonegap end** you will need to add the [whitelist plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to the `config.xml` and the associated `CSP` (Content Security Policy) to the HTML pages. However, in your case you might want to go with an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), such as [ionic](http://www.ionic.io/). To apply this *whitelist* system I will suggest you read this FAQ: [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Also worth noting, you can use a different architectural solution by loading the pages with the [file-transfer plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file-transfer).

Lastly, I would suggest you if you have further question, you should ask at the [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap) - Best of Luck

Comment: hi thank you for the reply - you mentioned that SPA would be better - i will be creating a very big app so is it still suitable?

Comment: @AN11 to be clear, I do not use SPA. I do use similar framework of my own making. I have also use multiple page frameworks. With the right patience, they all work. I suggest SPA (like ionic/angular) because it is the most popular and has been beat upon the most. Multi-page: [Hacker Dojo Calender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsdmasterindex.hackerDojocal) SPA-style: [Text-Only RSS Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsdmasterindex.text_only_rss_reader) Source code is online for both if interested